# Unmarshal yaml map dict key to struct property

Tags: go, yaml

I really searched a while here, but didn't found an adequate answer:

I am trying to unmarshall yaml dict keys onto a property of a struct rather than the key of a map.
Given this yaml

```yaml
commands:
    php:
        service: php
        bin: /bin/php
    node:
        service: node
        bin: /bin/node
```

I am able to unmarshall this into a struct like this:

```golang
type Config struct {
    Commands map[string]struct {
        Service string
        Bin     string
    }
}
```

But how am I able to unmarshall it into a struct like this:

```golang
type Config struct {
    Commands []struct {
        Name    string    // <-- this should be key from the yaml (i.e. php or node)
        Service string
        Bin     string
    }
}
```

Thx in advance for the help

Comment: yaml is not support by stdlib encoding package so mentioning which thirdparty library you're using might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom unmarshaler, like this ([on Go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/naKA-qVc3KC)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

var input []byte = []byte(`
commands:
    php:
        service: php
        bin: /bin/php
    node:
        service: node
        bin: /bin/node
`)

type Command struct {
    Service string
    Bin     string
}

type NamedCommand struct {
    Command
    Name string
}

type NamedCommands []NamedCommand

type Config struct {
    Commands NamedCommands
}

func (p *NamedCommands) UnmarshalYAML(value *yaml.Node) error {
    if value.Kind != yaml.MappingNode {
        return fmt.Errorf("`commands` must contain YAML mapping, has %v", value.Kind)
    }
    *p = make([]NamedCommand, len(value.Content)/2)
    for i := 0; i < len(value.Content); i += 2 {
        var res = &(*p)[i/2]
        if err := value.Content[i].Decode(&res.Name); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if err := value.Content[i+1].Decode(&res.Command); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    var f Config
    var err error
    if err = yaml.Unmarshal(input, &f); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, cmd := range f.Commands {
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", cmd)
    }
}
```

I have split the command data into `Command` and `NamedCommand` to make the code simpler, since you can just call `Decode` giving the embedded `Command` struct for the values. If everything was in the same struct, you'd need to manually map keys to struct fields.

Comment: Thank you, this works. Is it not possible to do this via yaml tags somehow?

Comment: @bambamboole I am unsure what you mean. Your question was about loading the *given* YAML, which doesn't contain tags, so you can't use tags to solve this problem. For reference, YAML tags are `!foo` etc in the YAML file. You might be talking about *Go tags* which are \`yaml:"…"\` in the Go sources. They are [rather limited](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v3#Marshal) and do not allow you to do this – however nothing stops you from writing your custom unmarshaling framework that processes custom tags on struct fields. This would be too complex for an SO answer though.

Comment: thx for context! I accepted it as the correct answer and will go on with this :)